# facebook comment not working

Tags: facebook, facebook-comments

in my website front page few thumbnail are there when we click on those thumbnail it shows the gallery just like facebook i am trying to implement facebook comment on that when i click on any of the thumnail first time facebook comment box will be shown and when i click on next photo of that gallery facebook comment will not be shown however my gallery each photos has one absolute url and i am defining that url in facebook comment code.here is my code.

my url is way2enjoy.com you can click on any photo there and see that for first photo comment will appear.

```
    <div id="fb-root"></div>
      <script>(function(d, s, id) {
      var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
     js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_GB/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=114744998704777";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, \'script\', \'facebook-jssdk\'));</script>
   <div class="fb-comments" data-width="340" data-     href="http://way2enjoy.com/photos/view/'.$id.'"   data-num-posts="10" data-      colorscheme="light"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comments plugin is not being rendered on load (it's added after), you need to run `FB.XFBML.parse()` after adding.

Comment: `FB.XFBML.parse()` is a JavaScript function that is a part of JS SDK, however you adding the comments plugin, it's after the page has already rendered so the comments plugin isn't rendered. You need to get it to render by calling the parse function after you add the comments plugin.